# Enum value collision with enum name

Tags: c++, gcc, enums

Let's take a code construction that I've recently found somewhere in project:

```
namespace Test
{
    enum EName
    {
        CoolEnum,
        NiceEnum
    };

    enum CoolEnum
    {
        CoolVal1,
        CoolVal2
    };

    enum NiceEnum
    {
        NiceVal1,
        NiceVal2
    };
}
```

My question is why the compiler allows something like this. Let's take a code sample here:

```
Test::CoolEnum cEnum = Test::NiceVal1; // INVALID, as compiler refers to Test::CoolEnum value of Test::Ename enum
```

Why is such confusion allowed? I understand why I have to prepend enum keyword, so the compiler clearly knows that I'm declaring a variable of given enum, not using value of other enum in the same namespace. I just don't understand why in the first place it's even possible to make such a construction.

Comment: I guess it's compiler defined because that code on Ideone causes errors: http://ideone.com/4GDTF

Comment: That's why I've placed gcc but as far as I know vc also allows such construction

Comment: @Kamil you may want to change the names of the enum constants of NiceEnum, since you copy-pasted it from CoolEnum and they conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is because the standard dictates this behavior. See 3.3.7/2:

> A class name (9.1) or enumeration name (7.2) can be hidden by the name
>   of an object, function, or enumerator declared in the same scope. If a
>   class or enumeration name and an object, function, or enumerator are
>   declared in the same scope (in any order) with the same name, the
>   class or enumeration name is hidden wherever the object, function, or
>   enumerator name is visible.

Presumably this is to facilitate compatibility with C's mechanism (where an enumerator doesn't open a new scope) which has been established for a long time.

In your case, at least with g++ you can use `typename` to indicate you want to use the type instead of the enumerator (`typename Test::CoolEnum cEnum = Test::NiceVal1;`).

In general however I like to scope all enumerations in a separate namespace or class to prevent these collisions completely.

Comment: "typename Test::CoolEnum" is incorrect - GCC happens to accept that [but should reject it](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48920). Use "enum Test::CoolEnum" instead.

Answer (score 9):

C++11's enum classes are the solution for this:

```
namespace Test
{
    enum class EName
    {
        CoolEnum,
        NiceEnum
    };

    enum class CoolEnum
    {
        NiceVal1,
        NiceVal2
    };

    enum class NiceEnum
    {
        NiceVal1,
        NiceVal2
    };
}
```

Then you can use the appropiate `NiceVal1`:

```
Test::CoolEnum cEnum = Test::CoolEnum::NiceVal1;
```

Plain enums were inherited from C, where there is no notion of what a namespace is. If plain enums introduced some kind of namespace, C code which uses enums would not compile at all. That's why enum classes were introduced, in order not to break backward compatibility.

Comment: Good to know, but it's not an answer to given question. I'm happy that in C++11 they cleared things out, but I'm just wondering why in first place it was possible

Comment: I've placed same construction outside of the namespace and still it's perfectly valid for C++

Comment: I don't understand what you are referring to, could you expand or provide an example?

Comment: I think i missunderstood your statement: "If plain enums introduced some kind of namespace, C code which uses enums would not compile at all."

Comment: I meant that if C++ plain enums where modified and acted like enum classes, then C code would not compile. These features inherited from C can't be changed. You can only add new ones which fix the problems in them.